# How to change value of KeyValuePair in a List as a value in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have quite complicated case. I want to change the value of the KeyVluePair in this Dictionary ->  `Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>`

So far I've done this but I don't know how to continue:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>> dworfs = new Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>();
while (input != "Once upon a time")
{
   string[] elements = input.Split(new[] { " <:> " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   if (dworfs.ContainsKey(elements[0]))
   {
      if (dworfs[elements[0]].Any(x => x.Key.Contains(elements[1])))
      {
         var dworf = dworfs[elements[0]].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == elements[1]);
         if (dworf.Value < int.Parse(elements[2]))
         {
            dworfs[elements[0]].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == elements[1]) = new KeyValuePair<string,int> (elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2]));
         }
      }
      else
      {
         dworfs[elements[0]].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2])));
      }
   }
   else
   {
      dworfs.Add(elements[0], new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> { new KeyValuePair<string, int> (elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2])) });
   }
   input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This line `dworfs[elements[0]].FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == elements[1]) = new KeyValuePair<string,int> (elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2]));` gives me an error **The left hand-side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer**. I don't know how to assign the value. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message describes the issue, the `FirstOrDefault()` will return with a value which can be only used as the right part of an expression. You can't assign values to method results.

Try this:

```
var index = dworfs[elements[0]].IndexOf(dworf);
dworfs[elements[0]][index] = new KeyValuePair<string,int> (elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2]));
```

Keep in mind that `FirstOrDefault()` could return null but you are not checking for that case in your code, that could lead `NullReferenceException`s.

Answer (score 1):

If `KeyValuePair` was a `Dictionary` you would have more chance.

However

```
var dwarf = dworfs[elements[0]];
var obj = dwarf.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == elements[1]);
var index = dwarf.IndexOf(obj);

dwarf[index] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(elements[1], int.Parse(elements[2]));
```

**Tip** you don't need to do everything on one line

Comment: Actually you have a mistake on of your lines. It should be `var object = dwarf.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == elements[1]);` Thank you. It helped me.